# Remove and navigate a fragment from a specific location in fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

This question has been asked before but wasnt the exact answer I was looking for.

Suppose my back stack is: A>B>C>D>E>F>G with A being the first fragment. If I only want to remove E and navigate the user to D while keeping the other fragments in the backstack. My back stack would then look like: A>B>C>D>F>G.

Im basically trying to make something like Instagram navigation, where the browsing history of the user is saved for each item of the bottom navigation menu.

Is it possible to do this? Do I use the remove() method from FragmentTransaction? Do I have to implement a custom back stack? If so can someone point me in the right direction? Also I dont understand kotlin so please write any code in Java.

Thanks

Comment: If you try to use navigation architecture components you can solve it. transactions make it hard to do it.

Comment: @JDevoloper can navigation components be used to implement seperate back stacks? I cant seem to find anything regarding that

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started. You can learn from here.. probably you can, but I dont suggest it.

Comment: @JDevoloper I read about it and tried it as well, but no luck with the seperate back stacks. I checked aroundthe internet and apparently I can do it by having seperate containers and hide/show them as needed. Is that a good idea?

Comment: If you don't have better solution, you make it like you said. You can set directions to your back stacks. Directions will manage your fragments. For example, when you go to D then you want to go to B, You can set directions to navigate your fragments. I mean there is a method popBackStack(); If you don't add any paramater it's going back last fragment. but if you set an action id it goes back the fragment that you set.

Comment: Alright thanks for all the help!